# Suppes definition of a set

Tags: set-theory

Just beginning to study Suppes "Axiomatic Set Theory" carefully. Early on, in Section 2.2, Definition 1,  he gives the following seminal definition of a set:

y is a set $\Leftrightarrow$ There exists x as an element of y OR y is the empty set

From this definition it appears that the "set of all sets" is a set, since it has elements. Does one infer the existence of the set of all sets? Why not? It is not precluded by the definition. I know it produces contradictions, but where does Suppes reconcile this? I have seen (apparently better) definitions of a set, namely as an object that is itself an element of another object. Quite the opposite of Suppes definition.

Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: I see nothing in that definition says a universal set has to exist. In fact, there is nothing in that definition that says anything exists, not even the empty set. Definitions such as this introduce no new logic. They just give an easier way to discuss the existing logic. If you could prove the universal set exists from this definition, then you could prove $\exists y\forall x(x \in y)$ without the definition, which is the same thing. As for your other definition, it assumes there are no ur-elements (a common practice, but a limitation none-the-less), and it doesn't capture the idea of "set".

Comment: Thank you for the response.... I was reading more into the definition than I should.

Comment: It seems to me that @GaryJones is right and the set of all sets is a set with this definition. If we denote S the class of all sets, then there exists an element y in S, so by the above definition S should be a set. Where is the problem with this argument?

Answer (score 0):

Although the definition defines the notion of set, it doesn't prescribe how it would come to contain elements, that is left to the Axioms.

Comment: You are answering a question that is over six years old and had no activity for over a year.